# Azure web service ip address

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a question regarding the IP address of my web application.
I deployed my app to azure. The application (API) has been successfully deployed to azure web service and for a client to make a request to the API, the IP address of the app is needed. In azure portal under properties I can find the virtual IP address (e.g. 20.10.200.5 typing it to the browser gives 404) and outbound API addresses.

How to make the API's virtual IP address reachable by clients  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't access an Azure App service directly by virtual IP. Virtual IP is bind to the App service plan, one App service plan could contain multiple Azure App services. App service plan maps the domain name with the individual app services, so using a virtual IP is not possible to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to [Stanley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65558982/1945525):

The App Service gets its own URL in the form of `<appservice-name>.azurewebsites.net` which can be used to access the application / API. You can also [Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) making the application / API available through your own domain, like `yourdomain.com/api`.